# JavaScript Date() formatting and calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to get date from `input` which format is dd-mm-yyyy when this is set via Bootstrap Date Picker and base on this date calculate end of the week. Somehow I get some weird results.

```
 $('#date-start').on('changeDate', function(){
        var objThs = $(this);
        if(objThs.parent().is('.reportDateWeeks')){
            var arrDateEl = objThs.val().split("-"),
                datStartDate = new Date(arrDateEl[2], arrDateEl[1] -1, arrDateEl[0]),
                datEndDate= new Date(datStartDate.setDate(datStartDate.getDate()+7)),
                datEndDateFormated = datEndDate.getDate() + '-' + datEndDate.getMonth() + 1 + '-' + datEndDate.getFullYear();

            console.log('start ' + objThs.val());
            console.log('end' + datEndDateFormated);

        }
    });
```

e.g. if I chose 04-05-2014 then console returns me:

start 04-05-2014

end 11-41-2014

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems.

1. You switched month and day in the result.
2. You should add parentheses around `datEndDate.getMonth() + 1`. Otherwise the `1` will be added as a string, not a number (producing the `41` in your example).

So the fixed could would look like:

```
var datEndDateFormated = (datEndDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' 
    + datEndDate.getDate() + '-' 
    + datEndDate.getFullYear();
```

Comment: Enclosing in brackets is a good idea, but use parseInt to be more reliable with the data type.

Comment: @Vimal Why do you need `parseInt` here? `getMonth()` always returns a number. `1` is always a number. The result will be used as a string anyways. I don't see the point.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I found solution...

```
 datEndDateFormated = datEndDate.getDate() + '-' + datEndDate.getMonth() + '-' + datEndDate.getFullYear();
```

I was so blind.. sory about that

Comment: This does not seem to be a working solution. You need the `+ 1` and the day and month are still switched.

Answer (score -1):

Use parseInt method to convert string to integer and then +1 to it.

```
datEndDateFormatted = datEndDate.getDate() + '-' + parseInt(datEndDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + datEndDate.getFullYear();
```